# How to get the input value from form to controller and store in a variable?

Tags: yii2

I have a form page in which that there are 3 input fields connected to database, now i need to add a new input field and get the values in variable in my controller page.

I have tried with constants my function is working properly but i need variables to do in my function

my form page

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idnew_table')->textInput(['maxlength' => 5,'style'=>'width:100px']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'adcaddress1')->textInput(['maxlength' => 5,'style'=>'width:200px']) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'adcaddress2')->textInput(['maxlength' => 5,'style'=>'width:200px']) ?>
<label>Value:</label><br>
   <input type="text" name="submitvalue" value=""><br><br>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

my controller function is,

```
public function actionCreate($data=null,$data1=null,$data2=null)
{
    $model = new Adcaddress();
    $this->layout='admin';
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->idnew_table]);

    } else {

            $data2 = "variable";
            $my_file1 = 'test.txt';
            $handle1 = fopen($my_file1, 'r');
            $data  = $handle1;
            $data = fread($handle1,filesize($my_file1));           
            $my_file = 'file.txt';
            $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
            //$data = $handle;
            fwrite($handle, "$data2"); 
       // return $this->render('create', [                'model' => $model, ]);
             return $this->render('create', array('data' => $data,'data1' => $data1,'data2'=>$data2,
                             'model' => $model));
    }
```

i need the  value of name=submitvalue in my variable $data2 in my controller page.

Comment: `Yii::$app->request->post()` have `submitvalue`. Try dumping post data.

Comment: Try this:
$data2 =Yii::$app->request->post('submitvalue');

Comment: @Vandro.nds Its not working i think the input type in form page is wrong.any suggestions about that please?

Comment: @InsaneSkull    is the input type i have used is correct ?

Comment: @sabarilogesh see the [official doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests)

Comment: Dear friend; In your code, **post values** are only set to `if`. And not in `else`. Meaning your code: **if the post method** received something then ...  **otherwise** ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`

load only the attribute related  to the model contained  in $_POST

the input you added  named 'submitvalue' is not declared as a part of the  model 
(the name of attrribute model is by default as  ModelName[attribute])

and then is not automatically loaded in the $model

if you need  the content of  the $_POST and work on it for inspecting you could  use

```
  $post  = Yii::$app->request->post(); 
  var_dump($post);
```